# PowerShell Error when queuing a build via Invoke-RestMethod and put

Tags: powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

Getting this error  when trying  to update a role to an endpoint using Powershell. It is crating the endpoints, just the roles update is giving error. same role update api call command works from postman.

```
$ApplyRole="https://Myorg/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/72505f4d-564c-41cf-14508b977f52_f6a1c4f9-a043-4399-1aad7b5cf19c/?api-version=5.0-preview"
```

```
$ApplyRole = "https://Myorg/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/72505f4d-564c-41cf-14508b977f52_f6a1c4f9-a043-4399-1aad7b5cf19c/?api-version=5.0-preview"

$Body1 = @{
  roleName = "User"
  userId   = "f0e736e3-0e73-4fd2-8b7a-615126eac692"
} 

$Bodyjson = $Body1 | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -uri $ApplyRole -Method Put -Credential $mycreds -Body $Bodyjson -ContentType "application/json"
```

Error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","typeName":"System.NullReferenceException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"NullReferenceException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

Comment: The error is being returned by the web service you're calling. Without knowing what input that web service expects, we won't be able to help you. You've either hit a bug in the web service, or a missing piece of input data is handled ungracefully.

Comment: It is creating the endpoints without any issues. Just not able to add the roles.Any other way to troubleshoot the error? This is the link I used as a reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Since the same API call command works from postman I am not sure why it doesnot work from the script.  Here is a reference I used https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/261328/adding-role-to-service-endpoint-via-vsts-api.html

Comment: Based on your link, I've added a hopefully relevant tag to your question, which may attract users familiar with the technology - adding all relevant tags is important. The only thing that jumps out at the linked page is that the body JSON seems to be an _array_ there (`[ { ... } ]`), unlike in your code.

Comment: Hi @user3634685, If below answer resolved your question, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open pipeline definition->click the tab variables->add variable `pat` and change variable type to secret.
Add task powershell and enter the script.

```
$connectionToken="$(pat)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$ApplyRole = "https://Myorg/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/{project id}_{endpoint id}/?api-version=5.0-preview" 

$body ="[{ 
 
`"roleName`": `"User`",
`"userId`": `"{group or user id}`"

}]"
$Roles = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ApplyRole -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method PUT
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
Actually it was an issue with the body syntax.
Added like this and it works.

```
 $Body1 = @"
                            [{
                            "roleName":"User",
                            "userId":"f0e736e3-0e73-4fd2-8b7a-615126eac692"
                            }]"@
```

Comment: Hi @user3634685, Thanks for your sharing, you can also try the sample I shared below. It also works. In addition, you could [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), In this case, others could directly find the useful solution and we could archive this thread. Thanks